# K means distance - Java

Tags: java

I am working on k-means and I am currently implementing a method to compute the new error as the average distance of each data point from the new center of its cluster.

Currently, I have a `List` of `List`s called `clusterList` where every data point is assigned to a cluster. For example, if I have 3 clusters and 8 data points, then the size of `clusterList` will be 2 (from index 0 to 2). I have another method called `distance` that assigns each data point to a cluster.

How can I calculate the average distance of each data point from the new center of its cluster? Everything is the same in list of lists.

Comment: What's your attempt?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show your [mcve] and tell us what research you have done.